# How to integrate $\int_0^2\left(\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 e^{x^2}\,dx\right)dy$?

Tags: integration

> Evaluate $$\int_0^2\left(\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 e^{x^2}\,dx\right)dy$$

My approach:

Firstly I integrated $e^{x^2}$ with respect to $x$ and again I tried to integrate $x^2$ with respect to $x$. So my doubt is about that second step I performed. Is it correct?

Comment: Change the order of integration.

Comment: How on earth did you manage to integrate $e^{x^2}$? It's famous for not having an elementary integral!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and type out images and your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to switching the order of integration by graphing the region and preceding is presented in the article titled, "Critical perspectives of pedagogical approaches to reversing the order of integration in double integral", written by Dr. Christopher C. Tisdell. Here is an example of his idea in action.

---

> Evaluate $$\int_0^2\left(\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 e^{x^2}\,dx\right)dy$$

---

Use integration by parts. Let $u=\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1} e^{x^2} dx$, and let $y=v$. Then $dv=dy$ and $du=-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{y^2}{4}} dy$. We then are trying to calculate $\int_{0}^{2} u dv$.

As the part in the integration with $uv$ cancels out we then we have,

$$=\int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{2}ye^{\frac{y^2}{4}} dy$$

The substitution $w=\frac{y^2}{4}$.

$$=\int_{0}^{1} e^w dw$$

$$=e-1$$

Answer (score 2):

It's just
$$\int_0^2\left(\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 e^{x^2}\,dx\right)dy=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{2x}e^{x^2} dy\right)dx=\int_0^1 2xe^{x^2}dx=e^{x^2}\Big|_0^1=e-1$$